# What is a post count?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, casefeed

When analysing the chatter activity object, I see the property "post count" what does this mean? What exactly constitutes a post? **I am pretty sure that the feed track posts due to a status change are not included but I would like to know exactly what is included in "post count".**

I've read [the documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_ChatterActivity.htm) but find it rather vague.

**PostCount**

> Description: The number of FeedItems made by the ParentId.

**ParentId**

> Description:Identifier of the object type to which the ChatterActivity
>   is related. In API version 30.0, the ParentId must be a UserId or
>   SelfServiceUser ID.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you've already read the documentation or not ?

Comment: I have read the documentation, which is very detailed but it is not explicit as to what elements exactly are included, maybe it assumes the reader already knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is understandable that you're confused. While it may seem like there are three kinds of FeedItem records (text, link, and content), there are actually 26 (including deprecated) kinds of FeedItem records. (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_enums.htm - look for ConnectApi.​​​FeedItemType)

The question to ask is: While the usual three types of FeedItems obviously contribute to FeedCount, do automatically-generated types (like TrackedChange) and other "manually-created," such as RypplePost (Work.com badges)? And what about FeedItems like CaseComments, which are only created when Case Feed is turned on?

In my experience, only manually-created FeedItems, including those three standard types and any similar to them, contribute. I don't think that automatically-generated, such as TrackedChange, are included. The thing to explore is if automatic posts like ActivityPost (saying that a task was created) or Case Feed posts are included.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know, the PostCount is the number of FeedItems. I think your question is "what constitutes a FeedItem?"

From the Salesforce [FeedItem Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm):

> FeedItem represents an entry in the feed, such as changes in a record
>   feed, including text posts, link posts, and content posts. This object
>   is available in API version 21.0 and later. This object replaces
>   FeedPost.

That should answer your question.